# Blazor Webassembly Bunit test changing blazorCulture?

Tags: blazor-webassembly, bunit

I am trying to test the blazorCulture change using Bunit Test but I am unable to get and set the blazorCulture.

Below code works in the actual blazor Wasm application but not working within a Bunit

```
var js = Services.GetRequiredService<IJSRuntime>();
            var result = await js.InvokeAsync<string>("blazorCulture.get");

            if (result != null)
            {
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(result);
            }
            else
            {
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-De");
                await js.InvokeVoidAsync("blazorCulture.set", "de-De");
            }
```

What is the way to change the Rendered Components culture and language using Bunit test?

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking JavaScript, which bUnit does not run, it runs entirely in C#. However, bUnit does come with a fake JSInterop implementation, that you can use to verify that you have made the correct calls to your `blazorCulture.get` and `blazorCulture.set` methods.

In your test, you can write something like this:

```
// arrange
var ctx = new TestContext();
ctx.JSInterop.Setup<string>("blazorCulture.get").SetResult("da-DK");
ctx.JSInterop.SetupVoid("blazorCulture.set").SetVoidResult();

// act
...

// assert
var invocations = ctx.JSInterop.Invocations["blazorCulture.set"];
var argument = invocations[0].Arguments[0]; // assumes only one invocation with one argument
Assert.Equal("de-De", argument);
```

Learn more here: https://bunit.dev/docs/test-doubles/emulating-ijsruntime.html